# Esta dando o erro: Can't create table ao criar esta tabela no MySql usando foreign key

Tags: mysql

```
create table clientes
(
    cpf varchar(15) primary key,
    nome varchar(50),
    rg varchar(10),
    dt_nascimento date,
    senha varchar(10), 
    rua varchar (20),
    numero varchar(6),
    bairro varchar(20),
    cidade varchar(20),
    cep varchar(15), 
    estado varchar(20), 
    telefone varchar(15),
    estadia int(25)
);

create table apartamento
(
    registro int primary key auto_increment,
    cod_cliente varchar(15),
    valor float (5.2),
    dias varchar(25) ,
    CONSTRAINT fk_impar_clientes FOREIGN KEY(cod_cliente) 
    REFERENCES clientes(cpf) ON DELETE CASCATE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ FOREIGN KEY(dias)
    REFERENCES clientes(estadia) ON DELETE CASCATE
);
```

Comment: Faltou postar a outra tabela...

Comment: Incluir as duas

Answer (score 0):

O seu **maior** problema foi criar duas *chaves primária* para a mesma *tabela* (`clientes(cpf)` e `clientes(estadia)`):

```
CONSTRAINT fk_impar_clientes FOREIGN KEY(cod_cliente)
REFERENCES clientes(cpf) ON DELETE CASCATE,
CONSTRAINT fk_ FOREIGN KEY(dias)
REFERENCES clientes(estadia) ON DELETE CASCATE
```

> Se você já vai ter **todos** os dados do cliente, pra que colocar **duas chaves**? Os dados já serão todos vinculados com apenas uma chave!

- Recomenda-se criar uma coluna para cada registro, identificada como `id`. Logo, você não vai ter problema se um cliente for cadastrado *sem CPF*.
- A **chave estrangeira** *deve ser do mesmo tipo e tamanho* da **referência**.
- A *estadia* não deve fazer parte do cadastro do cliente, já que ele pode voltar ao *hotel* para uma nova *estadia*.

Sendo assim, vamos concluir com o código!

**Estrutura das tabelas:**

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    `id` INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cpf` VARCHAR(15),
    `nome` VARCHAR(50),
    `rg` VARCHAR(10),
    `dt_nascimento` DATE,
    `senha` VARCHAR(10),
    `rua` VARCHAR (20),
    `numero` VARCHAR(6),
    `bairro` VARCHAR(20),
    `cidade` VARCHAR(20),
    `cep` VARCHAR(15),
    `estado` VARCHAR(20),
    `telefone` VARCHAR(15),
    `estadia` INT(25)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE apartamento (
    `id` INT(10) primary key auto_increment,
    `idcliente` INT(10),
    `valor` float (5.2),
    `dias` INT(25)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Criação da chave estrangeira:**

```
ALTER TABLE `apartamento` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cliente` FOREIGN KEY(`idcliente`) REFERENCES `clientes`(`id`);
```

**Inserir alguns dados para fins de teste:**

```
INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES ( NULL, '111.111.111-11', 'Fulano', '2222222222', '2017-04-22', 'MiNhAsEnHa', 'AV BRASIL', '2247', 'Deodoro', 'RIO DE JANEIRO', '21615-338', 'RJ', '(21)1234-5678', 31 );
INSERT INTO `apartamento` VALUES ( NULL, 1, 1500, 45 );
```

**Testar os dados inseridos (#1):**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `apartamento` JOIN `clientes` ON `clientes`.`id` = `apartamento`.`idcliente`;
+----+-----------+-------+---------+----+----------------+--------+------------+---------------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------------+-----------+--------+---------------+
| id | idcliente | valor | estadia | id | cpf            | nome   | rg         | dt_nascimento | senha      | rua       | numero | bairro  | cidade         | cep       | estado | telefone      |
+----+-----------+-------+---------+----+----------------+--------+------------+---------------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------------+-----------+--------+---------------+
|  1 |         1 |  1500 |      45 |  1 | 111.111.111-11 | Fulano | 2222222222 | 2017-04-22    | MiNhAsEnHa | AV BRASIL | 2247   | Deodoro | RIO DE JANEIRO | 21615-338 | RJ     | (21)1234-5678 |
+----+-----------+-------+---------+----+----------------+--------+------------+---------------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------------+-----------+--------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Testar os dados inseridos (#2):**

```
mysql> SELECT `clientes`.`nome`, `apartamento`.`estadia`, `apartamento`.`valor` FROM `apartamento` JOIN `clientes` ON `clientes`.`id` = `apartamento`.`idcliente`;
+--------+---------+-------+
| nome   | estadia | valor |
+--------+---------+-------+
| Fulano |      45 |  1500 |
+--------+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> Minha fonte e uma boa dica para aprender **Chaves estrangeiras no *MySQL***:
>
> [Youtube: Curso em Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paZNDJAPT4E&list=PLHz_AreHm4dkBs-795Dsgvau_ekxg8g1r&index=16)